# Generate numerical range from Excel or .csv dataset

Tags: excel, csv, excel-formula, powerbi, vba

Working with some data sets containing an incomplete list of numbers (ex. 3, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 17, 22, 23, 24, 28, etc...) contained in a single column.

Hoping to compile them into a collection of hyphenated ranges more similar to 3, 7, 9-12, 17, 22-24, 28, etc...

Inputting location data within an area so data does not need to correlate to any other cells, just need to reduce the total data set from thousands of individual values to hopefully a few hundred numerical ranges

[Example data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9nwj.png)

Had assumed there would be a simple option for this but not having any luck in Excel or Power BI.

Thanks and all the best,

Trent

Comment: Are you hoping to do this on Windows?

Comment: Have access to Windows (7 and 10) and Mac OS Sierra with Excel 2016 or Numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure other users will have more elegant answers. If you just need a quick hack, this will do. The first row takes a little special treatment.

[image]

[image]

Here are the formulas from row 2 going across:

B2: `=IF(A2-1=A1,"",A2)`

C2: `=IF(AND(A2+1=A3,A2-1<>A1),"-","")`

D2: `=IF(A2+1=A3,"",A2)`

E2: `=IF(C2="-",INDEX(D2:D$11,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(D2:D$11),0)),"")`*

*This uses an array formula, so you'll need to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> after typing it. You'll also change `D$11` to reference the bottom row you're using.

F2: `=CONCAT(B2,C2,E2)`

Answer (score 0):

The subs bellow will sort the main column (A, Sheet1), and generate the results in a new column

---

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub CreateSets()
    Dim arr As Variant, workCol As Long, workSet As Range
    Dim r As Long, rCount As Long, lastVal As Long, ub As Long
    Set workSet = Sheet1.UsedRange.Columns(1)           '<-- Update Sheet1 and Col
    SortCol workSet             'Sort main column, and add a new column to its right
    arr = workSet.Resize(workSet.Rows.Count, 2)         'Copy the 2 columns to array
    ub = UBound(arr)
    For r = 1 To ub
        If r = ub Then
            arr(r, 2) = arr(r, 1)
            Exit For
        End If
        If arr(r + 1, 1) <> arr(r, 1) Then          'Ignore dupes
            lastVal = arr(r, 1)
            rCount = r
            If rCount < ub Then
                Do
                    If arr(rCount + 1, 1) = arr(rCount, 1) + 1 Then
                        lastVal = arr(rCount + 1, 1)
                        rCount = rCount + 1
                        If rCount = ub Then Exit Do
                    End If
                Loop While arr(rCount + 1, 1) = arr(rCount, 1) + 1
            End If
            arr(r, 2) = arr(r, 1)
            If lastVal <> arr(r, 1) Then            'If a set was found, skip it
                arr(r, 2) = arr(r, 2) & "-" & lastVal
                r = rCount
            End If
        End If
    Next
    workSet.Offset(, 1).NumberFormat = "@"          'Change 2nd column to Text format
    workSet.Resize(workSet.Rows.Count, 2) = arr     'Copy results back to range
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub SortCol(ByRef oneColRng As Range)
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    If Not oneColRng Is Nothing Then
        Set ws = oneColRng.Parent
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        With ws.Sort
            .SortFields.Clear
            .SortFields.Add Key:=oneColRng.Cells(1, 1), _
                            SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                            Order:=xlAscending
            .SetRange oneColRng
            .Header = xlNo           '<-- Change this to "xlYes" if there are Headers
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
        With oneColRng.Offset(, 1)
            .Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            .AutoFit
        End With
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
End Sub
```

---

[image: Sets - 1 of 2]
[image: Sets - 2 of 2]

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with`awk` something like this:

```
awk 'NR==1   {b=e=$1; next}         # first line, set begin and end of current range, move to next line
     $1==e+1 {e=$1; next}           # if this line contiguous with previous, update range end and move on
             {print b,e; b=e=$1}    # not contiguous, print last range, start new range
     END     {print b,e}' data.csv
```

Or, the same but as a one-liner:

```
awk 'NR==1{b=e=$1;next} $1==e+1{e=$1;next} {print b,e;b=e=$1} END{print b,e}' data.csv
```

**Sample Output**

```
3 3
7 7
9 12
17 17
22 24
28 28
3 3
7 7
9 12
17 17
22 24
28 28
```

The output can be reformatted to more closely match your needs, or you can run it through `awk` again:

```
awk 'NR==1{b=e=$1;next} $1==e+1{e=$1;next} {print b,e;b=e=$1} END{print b,e}' data.csv |
   awk '{x=$1; if($1!=$2)x=x "-" $2;print x}'
```

**Output**

```
3
7
9-12
17
22-24
28
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to try it with Power Query, you can do this:**

Start with your table of values:

[image]

Add an index column by clicking the "Add Column" tab, then "Index Column"

[image]

Add another column by clicking the "Add Column" tab, then "Custom Column" and typing `try if Number.From(#"Added Index"{[Index]}[Values]) = Number.From(#"Added Index"{[Index]+1}[Values])-1 then Text.From(Number.From(#"Added Index"{[Index]}[Values])) else Text.From(Number.From(#"Added Index"{[Index]}[Values])) & "-" & Text.From(Number.From(#"Added Index"{[Index]+1}[Values])-1) otherwise Text.From(Number.From(#"Added Index"{[Index]}[Values]))` in the "Custom column formula" box of the window that pops up.

[image]

You'll get this:

[image]

Here's the query code:

```
let
Source = Table1,
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "NewValues", each 
    try 
        if Number.From(#"Added Index"{[Index]}[Values]) = Number.From(#"Added Index"{[Index]+1}[Values])-1 
        then Text.From(Number.From(#"Added Index"{[Index]}[Values]))
        else Text.From(Number.From(#"Added Index"{[Index]}[Values])) & "-" & Text.From(Number.From(#"Added Index"{[Index]+1}[Values])-1) 
    otherwise Text.From(Number.From(#"Added Index"{[Index]}[Values])))
in
#"Added Custom1"
```

*I used the `Number.From` and `Text.From` to force proper types needed for the use of `+`, `-`, and `&`.*